# Undefined offset error on Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have "Undefined offset" error in Yii framework, I need go to first id if next id is null and if last id if previous id is null?

```
public static function getNextOrPrevId($currentId, $nextOrPrev)
{
    $records=NULL;
    if($nextOrPrev == "prev")
       $order="id DESC";
    if($nextOrPrev == "next")
       $order="id ASC";

    $records=Photo::model()->findAll(
       array('select'=>'id', 'order'=>$order)
       );

    foreach($records as $i=>$r)
       if($r->id == $currentId)
          return $records[$i+1]->id ? $records[$i+1]->id : NULL;
    return NULL;
}
```

**error line**

```
return $records[$i+1]->id ? $records[$i+1]->id : NULL;
```

Comment: what do you mean by  "and if last id if previous id is null?" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return isset($records[$i+1]) ? $records[$i+1]->id : NULL;
```

But really, you should directly [select the next id from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+select+next+id), not select all ids and loop through them one by one in PHP.

```
$record = Photo::model()->findAll(array(
    'select' => 'id',
    'order'  => $order,
    'where'  => "id > $currentId",
    'limit'  => 1
));
```

(I don't know Yii, so I'm just making the syntax up. You get the idea though.)

Answer (score -2):

Remember that PHP arrays are based zero... when you reach the last item in it, you are trying to retrive a value from the $records[$i+1]->id where $i maybe the index of the last item but with the 'plus one' doesn't exists!.

try to avoid using foreach and use the simple form of a FOR..

```
// Not like this
foreach($records as $i=>$r)
    if($r->id == $currentId)
        return $records[$i+1]->id ? $records[$i+1]->id : NULL;

// I recommend
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($records); $i++){
    if(isset($records[$i]) && $records[$i]->id == $currentId)
        return $records[$i]->id;
}
```

lol, sorry for my bad english but i hope I explained.

Greetings from Mx.

Comment: -1 -"Try to avoid foreach"... Do you have an authoritative reference to back this suggestion up?  `foreach` is "cleaner" syntax (just look at your own example) and acceptable especially in circumstances where the keys in the associative array are not sequential (which would break your approach).  It wasn't the use of `foreach` that broke this code, it was the use of `$i+1`.  This would have caused an error in the final loop of a classic `for` loop too.